# How can I get the character after the digits with a regex

Tags: php, regex

Suppose I have the following line:

```
1309270927C1642,61N654NONREF
```

Now I want to get the `C` or `D` after the first digits. Now there are a few rules here

1. The first 6 digits are always there
2. The 4 digits after that are optional
3. After that you have a `D` or a `C`.

Now I wanted to solve that with a look behind:

`/(?<=\d{6,10})D|C/` but that is not allowed in PHP.

So I tried a non capturing group `/(?:\d{6,10})D|C/`. But that captures `1309270927C` in stead of just `C`.

So my question is how can I just capture the `D` or a `C`?

Comment: Just as a side mention since no answer mentioned it, `(?:\d{6,10})D|C` will match against either `(?:\d{6,10})D` or `C`. If you want to make it match `(?:\d{6,10})` then either `D` or `C`, then you will need a group (capture group or non-capture group) to limit the scope of the `|` operator: `(?:\d{6,10})(D|C)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PCRE `\K` operator:

```
\d{6,10}\K[DC]
```

It will omit everything in the match up to `D` or `C`. You may further tweak this regex allowing or disallowing more characters to the character class `[DC]`.

Have a look at the [example](https://regex101.com/r/jU2yS0/1).

Sample code:

```
$re = "/\\d{6,10}\\K[DC]/"; 
$str = "1309270927C1642,61N654NONREF"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Also, here is some [more information](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) on `\K` operator:

> `The \K "keep out" verb, which is available in Perl, PCRE (C, PHP, R…)`
>   `and Ruby 2+. \K tells the engine to drop whatever it has matched so`
>   `far from the match to be returned.`
>
> `Instead of (?<=\b\d+_)[A-Z]+, you can therefore use \b\d+_\K[A-Z]+`

The limitations of `\K`:

Compared with lookbehinds, both the \K and capture group workarounds have limitations:

> ✽ When you look for multiple matches in a string, at the starting
>   position of each match attempt, a lookbehind can inspect the
>   characters behind the current position in the string. Therefore,
>   against 123, the pattern (?<=\d)\d (match a digit preceded by a digit)
>   will match both 2 and 3. In contrast, \d\K\d can only match 2, as the
>   starting position after the first match is immediately before the 3,
>   and there are not enough digits left for a second match. Likewise,
>   \d(\d) can only capture 2.
>
> ✽ With lookbehinds, you can impose multiple conditions (similar to our
>   password validation technique) by using multiple lookbehinds. For
>   instance, to match a digit that is preceded by a lower-case Greek
>   letter, you can use (?<=\p{Ll})(?<=\p{Greek})\d. The first lookbehind
>   (?<=\p{Ll}) ensures that the character immediately to the left is a
>   lower-case letter, and the second lookbehind (?<=\p{Greek}) ensures
>   that the character immediately to the left belongs to the Greek
>   script. With the workarounds, you could use \p{Greek}\K\d to match a
>   digit preceded by a character in the Greek script (or \p{Greek}(\d) to
>   capture it), but you cannot impose a second condition. To get over
>   this limitation, you could capture the Greek character and use a
>   second regex to check that it is a lower-case letter.

Output:

```
C
```

Comment: Same result with `/(?:\d{6,10})(D|C)/`, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @VladPreda: No, it is not. My regex returns just `C`, while yours returns `1309270927C`.

Comment: Works for me too. I wasn't sure whether `PHP` supports the `\K` option or not. The `\K` is pretty nice since it allows a *lookbehind* with a variable length

Comment: @hek2mgl: `\K` is supported in PHP, but it is not a full-fledged look-behind (it does not allow multiple backtracking).

Comment: @hek2mgl why is it bad?

Comment: @sanders No, nothing bad. I told it is nice. It is just not the same as a lookbehind, but in your case the perfect solution.

Comment: Well i don't get that from you previous comment

Comment: It is not bad, it is just not a full-fledged look-behind. That is what @hek2mgl meant :-)

Answer (score 3):

I would use a [*capturing subpattern*](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php), like this:

```
$string = "1309270927C1642,61N654NONREF";
$pattern = '/\d{6,10}(C|D)/';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
// $matches[1] contains the contents of the first subpattern
echo $matches[1];
```